# Which diagram to use for visualizing connections between enterprise applications?

Tags: enterprise-architecture, diagrams

We got 30 or so enterprise applications, some interacting with each other. And I'd like to create a diagram to see the big picture.

Which diagram should I use? System context diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If visualizing the systems and the channels of communication between systems, a [component diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_diagram) is probably most appropriate.

If visualizing how the applications are deployed and the channels of communication, then a [deployment diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deployment_diagram) is suitable.

Comment: AFAIK neither component diagrams nor deployment diagrams focus on communication between the parts.

Comment: ... looking here, http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html, it seems component and deployment diagrams are categorized as *structural* diagrams, as opposed to *behavioral* diagrams. So, definitely no communication.

Comment: OP was asking to visualize the connections between applications, not the behavior of them. It sounds like he's looking for a structural diagram to me. The lines in the component diagram and deployment diagram visualize the channels of communication between components and deployments respectively.

Comment: My critics was not about what the OP was asking, but about your statements about component and deployment diagrams showing **communication**, which they don't, if one sticks to UML literally. And communication is a behavioural aspect.

Comment: The diagrams show channels of communication. I've edited my answer to read as such.

Comment: Maybe "channels of communication" can be expressed in a component diagram (I don't think this is true for a deployment diagram), but  I still don't think "communication" is in the focus. Maybe the OP is not interested in communication, only in structure, then your suggested diagram types are fine. However, when one wants to put focus on communication, there is only one type of diagram in UML currently available for this, and that is the one I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

UML 2.x introduced [information flow diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/information-flow-diagrams.html), which is probably what you are really looking for.

It seems the UML designers - finally, after years - came to the hindsight that they missed something in all the diagram types to show the data flow between components, at different levels of abstraction. Still they decided not to call this kind of diagrams ["data flow diagrams"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_flow_diagram), what IMHO would have been a much more suitable name.

I can only guess why, maybe because that name was in use years before UML became popular, maybe they did not like it because of the ["not invented here"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) syndrome. This [Wikipedia article about IFDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_flow_diagram) even contains a remark about not to confuse IFDs withs DFDs, but I would not take this seriously - IFDs are probably the only kind of data flow diagrams currently available in UML. If you want to stick to pure UML, and the diagram type is suffcient for your case, I would recommend to use it.

Comment: This kind of diagram doesn't seem big picture at all. It only illustrates a single use case and one kind of connection between applications when there could be many.

Comment: @Samuel: it seems you overgeneralized from the one example I linked to: just because there is only one use case shown, you got the misconception  information/data flow diagram were intended for this only.